# Laravel: Getting the value from select option Using Ajax & Jquery

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have question regarding to my codes, I have module which Admin can filter what the user ordered. The scenario Admin have/had a list of customers who ordered,admin will choose which customer Ex. **Customer 2** so now the url http://localhost:8000/customer_all_orders/2 **note: that the /2 is customer_id**
have record of 4 orders,

So now admin can filter the record, if admin select the dropdown **3 orders** the query will limit 3, **can also be limit 15 orders** etc..

- 3 orders
- 15 orders
- Show All Orders

**Question:Why the orders cannot limit the orders, if i select some value on my select option? but the status code is (OK)**

Result Here:
[image: Result Console]

---

**My Script/Controller:**

```
public function customer_all_orders($id,Request $request) {

    $filter = $request->get('filter');
    if(isset($filter))
    {
        $customer_details_id = DB::select('SELECT * FROM customer_details WHERE customer_id = ? ',[$id]);

        $select_order_properties = DB::select('SELECT * FROM order_properties WHERE customer_id = ? ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT '.$filter.' ',[$id]);

        $select_order_details = DB::select('SELECT order_properties_id,menu_cat_image,or_number,Quantity,Subtotal,menu_cat_name FROM order_properties as op LEFT JOIN (SELECT order_properties_id,product_id,UnitPrice,Quantity,(UnitPrice * Quantity) as Subtotal FROM order_details_properties) odp ON op.order_id = odp.order_properties_id 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT menu_cat_image,menu_cat_name,menu_cat_id FROM menu_category) mc ON odp.product_id = mc.menu_cat_id
        WHERE customer_id = ?  ',[
            $id
        ]);

        return View('customer_all_orders')
        ->with('customer_details',$customer_details_id)
        ->with('order_properties',$select_order_properties)
        ->with('customer_order',$select_order_details);
    }
    else
    {
        $customer_details_id = DB::select('SELECT * FROM customer_details WHERE customer_id = ? ',[$id]);

        $select_order_properties = DB::select('SELECT * FROM order_properties WHERE customer_id = ? ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 4',[$id]);

        $select_order_details = DB::select('SELECT order_properties_id,menu_cat_image,or_number,Quantity,Subtotal,menu_cat_name FROM order_properties as op LEFT JOIN (SELECT order_properties_id,product_id,UnitPrice,Quantity,(UnitPrice * Quantity) as Subtotal FROM order_details_properties) odp ON op.order_id = odp.order_properties_id 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT menu_cat_image,menu_cat_name,menu_cat_id FROM menu_category) mc ON odp.product_id = mc.menu_cat_id
        WHERE customer_id = ?  ',[
            $id
        ]);


        return View('customer_all_orders')
        ->with('customer_details',$customer_details_id)
        ->with('order_properties',$select_order_properties)
        ->with('customer_order',$select_order_details);
    }


}
```

My Ajax Request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#filter_orders').on('change',function(){
                    var value = this.value;
                    var customer_id = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-user-id');

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'/customer_all_orders/' + customer_id,
                        type:'get',
                        data:{filter:value},
                        success:function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                        },
                        error: function(error){
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    })


                });
            })
```

My Html:

```
<select class="form-control" id="filter_orders" data-user-id='{{$details->customer_id}}'>
                <option value="" selected="">Select Filter Orders</option>
                <option value="3" data-user-id='{{$details->customer_id}}'>Last 3 Orders</option>
                <option value="15" data-user-id='{{$details->customer_id}}'>Last 15 Orders</option>
                <option value="*" data-user-id='{{$details->customer_id}}'>Show all Orders</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: You don't have a route defined for `/customer_all_orders`, do you?

Comment: I dont have route for /customer_all_orders i have only /customer_all_orders/id because i select first the user before i filter there orders.

Comment: That's why it is failing. Your AJAX route is wrong. So you'd need to pass the user id in there.

Comment: how to pass it there? i confuse with that Moza

Comment: in your ajax call add the customer ID as parameter for the route: `url:'/customer_all_orders' + customerId`. `¢ustomerId` may be a data attribute in a data attribute in your select

Comment: yah i already did that, however the result not showing.